# Kolmogorov Equations for a 3 state model. CTMC with a 3x3 generator matrix. Solving for $p_{11}$

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process

I have a matrix $Q= \left[
    \begin{array}{ccc}
      -3&3&0\\
      2&-5&3\\
0&4&-4
    \end{array}
\right] $ where the state space is $S=[0,1,2]$

> I need to solve the Kolmogorov Equations (backward OR forward), I chose forward to find the value $p_{1,1}(t)$.

**I have:** $$p'_{11}(t)=p_{10}(t)q_{01}+p_{11}(t)q_{11}+p_{12}(t)q_{21}$$
By playing around and solving for $p'_{10}(t)$ and $p'_{12}(t)$ I get:
$$p'_{11}(t)=-p'_{10}(t)-p'_{12}(t)$$

Now, if I only had 2 variable, I'd be able to rearrange and integrate to solve for $p_{11}(t)$, but I don't know how to handle 3 variables.

I'm left to solve $p'_{10}=-3p_{10}+2p_{11}$. I know that $p_{11}=1-p_{10}-p_{12}$ and again this is 2 variables.

Can somebody help me out?

Comment: You do realize that there are a total of 9 Kolmogorov equations, one for each $p_{ij}$? 9 unknowns, 9 equations, is solvable.

Comment: So which state should I look at first? Ideally the one containing $q_{02}$and $q_{20}$, but such thing doesn't exist in a single equation, so it'll be very tedius to figure out, right?

Comment: Did you find the way to solve a 3-state system?  Could you share your results here, please?